# Read only PropertyGrid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a way to make an ExtJS4 PropertyGrid (Ext.grid.property.Grid) non-editable?

There is no "editable" or "readonly" config option AFAICS.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but there is a disabled config that defaults to false, try setting that to true?

Comment: @Amalea nice idea, but it just disables the thing entirely, giving an empty grey panel (as you would expect I guess)

Comment: ... actually no, it does display the properties, but under a semitransparent grey mask.  It should work if I can get rid of that mask somehow

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to add a listener, that prevents starting the editing component:

```
    listeners: {
        'beforeedit': {
            fn: function () {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this solution is, that one can not mark a cell to copy (Ctrl+C) the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sourceConfig` to set the editor to a `Ext.form.DisplayField`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.PropertyGrid', {
    sourceConfig: {
        field1: {
            displayName: 'Editable Field'
        },
        field2: {
            displayName: 'Readonly Field',
            editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.DisplayField')
        }
    },
    source: {
        field1: "Some property",
        field2: "Some other property",
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One more decision, but don't allow to select text thereafter: `myGrid.findPlugin('cellediting').disable();`

Comment: This worked for me in extjs 6.5.3. I made the call in the afterrender event handler.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to prevent the selection of any cell:

```
var myPropertyGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', { ... });
myPropertyGrid.getSelectionModel().setLocked(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyPropertyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',
    xtype: 'mypropertygrid',
    source: {
        field1: 'value of field1',
        field2: 'value of field2'
    },
    sourceConfig: {
        field1: {
            editor: {disabled: true}
        },
        field2: {
            editor: {disabled: true}
        }
    }
});
```

I test it on Extjs 6.0.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.